# Using R, compare the 90th percentile between two groups

Tags: r

Given a table with two columns, Group and Response time and want to compare the ResponseTimes between the two groups. I can do this easily with t.test:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  Group = sample(c("Before", "After"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  ResponseTime = rnorm(100, mean = c(10, 15), sd = 2)
)

t.test(data$ResponseTime[data$Group == "Before"],
       data$ResponseTime[data$Group == "After"])
```

But, I want to compare the two groups in terms of 90th percentile, still getting p-value, difference, and 95% CI.

Is there a test to do this? Does it even make sense to report this instead of means?

I'm doing it because ResponseTimes are typically reported at the 90th percentile, not mean.

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: I think you could try with quantile regression with `quantreg` package. In your case the regression model would be `rq(formula = data$ResponseTime ~ data$Group, tau = 0.9)` . You would essentially get an estimate of difference in 90th percentile.

For p-values and CI, I think that you need bootstrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on *@atomasevic*'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77673089/using-r-compare-the-90th-percentile-between-two-groups#comment136935631_77673089), we can use `quantreg::rq` and `se='boot'` in `summary()`.

```
> quantreg::rq(formula = data$ResponseTime ~ data$Group, tau = 0.9) |> summary(se='boot')

Call: quantreg::rq(formula = data$ResponseTime ~ data$Group, tau = 0.9)

tau: [1] 0.9

Coefficients:
                 Value    Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)      17.26267  0.65927   26.18448  0.00000
data$GroupBefore -1.59911  0.80321   -1.99091  0.04928
```